# EntityAPI $controller->view() not working!

Tags: views, entities

i have created new entity using Model Entity module. Now i would like to have a new page where i can list multiple Model contents.
I have defined new page in hook_menu():

```
// Menu item for viewing model list of current account
$items['model'] = array(
  //'title' => 'Title',
  'title callback' => 'My Models',
  'page callback' => 'model_list_view', 
  'access callback' => 'model_access',
  'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

And here is definition of function model_list_view()

```
function model_list_view() {
  global $user;
  $account = $user;
  //Load user models
  $conditions = array('uid' => $account->uid);
  $models = array_values(model_load_multiple(FALSE, array('uid' => $account->uid)));

  // Render models
  $controller = entity_get_controller('model');  
  $new_models = array();
  foreach($models as $model){
    $new_model[$model->model_id] = $model;
  }
  $content = $controller->view(array($new_model));
  drupal_set_title('My models');
  return $content;
}
```

So after this i am getting the following error:

- Missing bundle property on entity of type protocol. in entity_extract_ids()

With this function i am trying to get a View which lists the supplied array of models. I would highly appreciate if someone can show whats the right way to render array of contents via View **programmatically**. I have searched a lot about this but couldn't really find sth that would explain stepwise.

Thanks in advance!